# How to create docker images inside minikube registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, minikube

I'm trying to use kubernetes locally. Thus I installed minikube. When I create deployment object, pods can't find the images within minikube docker registry and pods' show status as `ErrImageNeverPull`. To solve the problem I followed these steps:

1. `minikube start`
2. `eval $(minikube docker-env)`
3. I changed `ImagePullPolicy` to `Never` in deployment.yaml file
4. `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d`

Even though I followed all these steps images for the project not being created within minikube registry. I have double checked it by running this command `eval $(minikube docker-env -u)` in order to switch back to the local docker registry. Images and Containers have been created within local docker registry.

My question is how can I create docker images within minikube docker registry?

Comment: Hi Elshan, I've edited the answer I posted to you, because I believe I found the main issue you had. If you have any doubt let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem by following these steps:

1. Restarted minikube by executing `minikube start`
2. I ran `minikube -p minikube docker-env` and it returned following:

   [image: output of command]
3. I executed `eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)`
4. Then I ran `docker-compose` commands.

Images and Containers was created within minikube docker registry.

To be honest I don't know why `eval $(minikube docker-env)` didn't do the job and the differences between `eval $(minikube docker-env)` and `eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)`.

If you know the reason please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications. With Compose, you use a YAML file to configure your application’s services. Then, with a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration.

- That's probably the reason why the `eval` didn't work, because the eval is made for `docker` binary, not `docker-compose`. Use a Dockerfile to run `docker build` and it should be registered directly to Minikube Image Registry.

from Minikube Documentation: [Comparing 5 ways to push your image into a minikiube cluster](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/), the best way to do it is as describe below:

> My question is how can I create docker images within minikube docker registry?

- You can run `minikube ssh` and you can build the images directly on the Minikube VM. The Docker environment is already set there:

```
$ minikube ssh
                         _             _            
            _         _ ( )           ( )           
  ___ ___  (_)  ___  (_)| |/')  _   _ | |_      __  
/' _ ` _ `\| |/' _ `\| || , <  ( ) ( )| '_`\  /'__`\
| ( ) ( ) || || ( ) || || |\`\ | (_) || |_) )(  ___/
(_) (_) (_)(_)(_) (_)(_)(_) (_)`\___/'(_,__/'`\____)


$ docker images
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx                latest              e791337790a6        3 days ago          127MB
nginx                <none>              ed21b7a8aee9        2 weeks ago         127MB
ubuntu               latest              4e5021d210f6        4 weeks ago         64.2MB
```

- Remember, you have to use the standard `docker build` to register the images into the registry. `docker-compose` is not baked inside Minikube VM

Let me know in the comments if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and time @willrof . 

I agree with you, `docker-compose` is not baked inside Minikube. Actually that's why I don't want to ssh into Minikube VM. Because by doing this I should build every single project required image with `docker build` command.  And I want to take advantages of `docker-compose` .

Actually a day ago I was successful by following steps I have mentioned above. 

For some reason these steps don't work anymore.

Comment: @ElshanAkberov I was going to look into your issue and I saw you posted an answer. I'm happy you found the solution for your issue. Please mark your answer as accepted, since it solved your problem, this way it can help others with similar issues. Also if you could consider upvoting my answer as a recognition it was well researched and time consuming I'd appreciate very much.